# Почему метод класса не вызывается?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pygame

Есть класс, экземпляр которого рисует квадрат. Я же хочу что бы при нажатии на квадрат он менял, например, ширину рамки.

В условии `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` делать это не хочу.

Помогите разобраться, почему не вызывается метод `action_button`?

```
import pygame

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
size = (150, 150)
sc = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
sc.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game2")
fps = pygame.time.Clock()


class Button:
    def __init__(self, surface, color, rect, border_radius):
        self.surfase = surface
        self.color = color
        self.rect = rect
        self.border_radius = border_radius
        self.draw_switch = True
        self.switch_buttons()

#замысел такой - экземпляр класса рисует квадрат с рамкой 2, а если нажать на квадрат, метод draw         перестает работать и работает
#метод action_button
def switch_buttons(self):   
    if self.draw_switch:
        self.draw()
    else:
        self.action_button()

def draw(self):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        pygame.draw.rect(self.surfase, WHITE,
                     (self.rect[0] - 4, self.rect[1] - 4, self.rect[2] + 15, self.rect[3] + 15))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surfase, self.color, self.rect, self.border_radius)

        if self.rect[0] < mouse[0] < self.rect[0] + self.rect[2]\
                and self.rect[1] < mouse[1] < self.rect[1] + self.rect[3]:
            if click[0] == 1:
                print('кнопка')
                print(self.draw_switch)
                self.draw_switch = False
                print(self.draw_switch)

def action_button(self):  #почему эта чертова функция не вызывается?
    pygame.draw.rect(self.surfase, WHITE,
                     (self.rect[0] - 4, self.rect[1] - 4, self.rect[2] + 15, self.rect[3] + 15))
    pygame.draw.rect(self.surfase, self.color, self.rect, 4)
    print('action')


    def run_game():
    game = True
    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                game = False
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pygame.display.update()
        button0 = Button(sc, BLACK, (50, 50, 40, 40), 2)
        fps.tick(60)
        pygame.display.update()


run_game()
```

Comment: Что значит «не вызывается»? Что происходит вместо вызова? Что в консоли написано при этом?

Comment: кнопка
True
False.
в методе switch_buttons не выполняется условие else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не знаю правильно ли понимаю вас, но попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import pygame

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
size = (150, 150)
sc = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
sc.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game2")
fps = pygame.time.Clock()


class Button:
    def __init__(self, surface, color, rect, border_radius):
        self.surfase = surface
        self.color = color
        self.rect = rect
        self.border_radius = border_radius
        self.flag = True
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surfase, WHITE,
            (self.rect[0] - 4, self.rect[1] - 4, self.rect[2] + 15, self.rect[3] + 15))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surfase, self.color, self.rect, self.border_radius) 

    def draw(self):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if (self.rect[0] < mouse[0] < self.rect[0] + self.rect[2]\
                and self.rect[1] < mouse[1] < self.rect[1] + self.rect[3]): 
#                if click[0] == 1:
            if click[0] == 1 and self.flag:                                 # +++
                self.action_button()
                self.flag = False 
            elif click[0] == 1 and not self.flag:                           # +++     
                pygame.draw.rect(
                    self.surfase, 
                    WHITE,
                    (self.rect[0] - 4, self.rect[1] - 4, self.rect[2] + 15, self.rect[3] + 15)
                )
                pygame.draw.rect(self.surfase, self.color, self.rect, self.border_radius)                 
                self.flag = True 
             
    def action_button(self):  
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surfase, WHITE,
                         (self.rect[0] - 4, self.rect[1] - 4, self.rect[2] + 15, self.rect[3] + 15))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surfase, (250, 0, 0), self.rect, 4)
#        print('action')


def run_game():
    game = True
    button0 = Button(sc, BLACK, (50, 50, 40, 40), 2)                # +++
    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                game = False
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pygame.display.update()
#        button0 = Button(sc, RED, (50, 50, 40, 40), 2)             # ---
        button0.draw()                                              # +++
        fps.tick(60)
        pygame.display.update()

run_game()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, вы забыли вот в этом месте вызвать функцию `self.switch_buttons()`:

```
if click[0] == 1:
    print('кнопка')
    print(self.draw_switch)
    self.draw_switch = False
    print(self.draw_switch)
```

Надо добавить тут её вызов. Ну или где-то ещё. В данный момент логика работы программы у вас выглядит вообще несколько странной.

Comment: Но ведь при отжатии лкм метод draw не перестает работать.
В том то и замысел... По умолчанию работает метод draw, и если один раз нажать на квадрат, то draw перестает работать и включается метод action_button